# Call background service in iOS

Tags: android, ios

i’m new on iOS development.This is my task.
In android i developed two apps that share data: so when App A is in foreground, before make a server-side call, invokes a background service exposed by App B that retrieves some data from its internal db and pass them back to App A. 
Synthesizing, App A receive data from App B staying in foreground, so the User Interface control is always in the hands of App A.

Is it possibile make something similar in iOS environment ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is one of those things that's much better on Android!  :O

Answer (score 0):

You can use URL scheme to invoke the applications and send data across. However you need to design a better communication model to make it effective.

Comment: The problem using Custom URL is that the called App became that app in foreground, so in my case this means that App B called by App A would be the app in foreground. But i need that App A retrieves data from App B maintaining the UI control.

Answer (score 0):

We can not pass data from App A to App B with iOS standard functions. We will need to used something customise with URL scheme like invoke App B when App A is in background and call App B functions as we needed.

Comment: The problem using Custom URL is that the called App became that app in foreground, so in my case this means that App B called by App A would be the app in foreground. But i need that App A retrieves data from App B maintaining the UI control.